# Blueimp Gallery - Bootstrap Video Example?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, video, blueimp

I apologize for this question in advance, but neither google nor the SE search returned any results.

I am having troubles adding a video / videos into the Blueimp Gallery. the videos are all local mp4 videos and when adding them to the website via the in the documentation referenced markup, I only get a black screen without the video actually streaming.

```
<div class="box-body">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
      <div class="lightBoxGallery">
        <a href="link/to/video.mp4" title="Video Name" data-gallery=""><img src="/thumbnail/picture.img" style="height:100px; width:100px;"></a>
      </div>
      <!-- /.lightbox gallery -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /.row -->
</div>
<!-- /.box-body -->
```

what I would like is to have the video linked to a picture, and upon clicking the image, the Blueimp Gallery script should pop up and run the video accordingly.

Right now i am using the HTML5 video markup but thats not what I want...

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <video class="embed-responsive-item" height="240" controls>
      <source src="linkto/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</div>
```

How do I go about this? are there any examples I can look at?

Thanks

Comment: check your console

Comment: if you type the URL of the video you're trying to display directly into the browser does it work? if not, check you have the MIME types for mp4 set correctly on the server

Comment: MIME and URL is correct and video is playing just fine when using the `<video>` tag, the problem is IMO between bootstrap and blueimp. I cant seem to find any sample code online that shows how to add a video to the blueimp gallery though...